# Swift `reversed()` not ordering how I thought it would

Tags: swift

Why would this produce `Elena` instead of `Paula`?

```
let names = ["Paula", "Elena", "Zoe"]

var lastNameEndingInA: String?

for name in names.reversed() where name.hasSuffix("a") {
lastNameEndingInA = name
break
}

lastNameEndingInA // Optional("Elena")”
```

I would have thought that `names.reversed()` would be `[“Zoe”, “Paula”, “Elena”]` and then where `name.hasSuffix(“a”)` would skip “Zoe” and then go to “Paula” then `break` so `lastNameEndingInA` would be “Paula”?

I can’t figure out why it isn’t working like that though.

Comment: just remove the break keyword

Comment: Your reversed array is "Zoe", "Elena", "Paula". Why would you think it would be “Zoe”, “Paula”, “Elena” ?

Comment: @rmaddy You’re right.  I was thinking of sorted in reverse, instead of just reversed. I would need names.reversed().sorted.  Thanks!

Comment: @SRMR As I show in my answer, it needs to be `names.sorted().reversed()`. If you sort at the end it makes the reversal pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is ["Paula", "Elena", "Zoe"]. When reversed it is ["Zoe", "Elena", "Paula"]. There is no reason to think it would be [“Zoe”, “Paula”, “Elena”]. So your code is working as expected.

But it can be written more easily as:

```
let lastNameEndingInA = names.reversed().first { $0.hasSuffix("a") }
```

It you want the names sorted in reverse and then find the match, do:

```
let lastNameEndingInA = names.sorted().reversed().first { $0.hasSuffix("a") }
```

Comment: Yes I should actually be doing this! I will mark your answer correct in 8 minutes when it lets me. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `names.sorted().reversed()` to reverse a sort, use `names.sorted(by: >)`.